# Time-limited access to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, forms-authentication, date-time

An user should be given access to the SharePoint-Website. This access should be limited to a variable date or a timeframe. After this date/timeframe, the user should no more be able to access the SharePoint-Website.

Can you give a suggestion how to achieve that?

Environment: SharePoint 2013 Foundation with FBA configured

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for anything like this out of the box.

But if you're using your own Membership provider with the FBA, then you can implement the functionality in that, by either disallow the user after the specified date or remove a role after the date and use that role for giving access.

If you're using some standard Membership provider, then one solution could be to give people access to SharePoint through a group based on when they should expire and then disallow that group at the specified date using a timerjob, workflow, ...

Comment: So, my approach would be:
1. Create a sharepoint list which stores the user names and last day of access.
2. Create a timerjob (or even more basic: a scheduled task with powershell), which checks that list daily and disables users if necessary.

Is this possible?

This question is not that much about FBA, since FBA users can be handled inside sharepoint as standard AD users are handled, isnt it? I only started implementing FBA, so sorry if i am missing something out.